# Trigger php - get path - add img

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to PDO and HTML. How do I trigger the php file to get this random image path as the 'brand' image path in to my javascript?

php:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT img, subject FROM img_db WHERE availability = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array('Y');
$query->execute($array);

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

var_dump($result);
```

js:

```
(function() {
    var image = { 
        'brand': { 'url':'img/bimg.jpg', 'img':null },
        'item': { 'url':'img/fimg.jpg', 'img':null }
    };

var canvas = {'temp':null, 'draw':null};
var mouseDown = false;
```

Comment: Why isn't anyone answering?

Answer (score 0):

There are many attempts, but here's simplest one:

Prepare your array:

$arr = array();

```
forach($results as $result){
  $arr[$result['subject']] = array('url' => $result['img']); 
}
```

Convert your results to JSON

```
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

if you are using MVC framework, pass your `$json` to view.

Next, in JavaScript part of your page:

```
(function() {
    var image = <?php echo $json; ?>;

var canvas = {'temp':null, 'draw':null};
var mouseDown = false;
```

You can also load this data using `ajax`.